# How to automatically clear console history in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, console, history

I work in the chrome environment a lot. Occasionally I will run applications which take days to run, and I frequently encounter the "JS Heap out of memory error message".

I have discovered that this wasn't actually due to my own application, but due to Chrome's automatic console history saving.

At the moment, I periodically and manually clear the console history, but this is tedious and requires that I am present. Is there a way to do this automatically.

I've thought about simulating a keystroke and I've tried disabling "Autocomplete from history", but the latter doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

to my code solves it.